# Does numeric date require a time-zone, when creating a new Date object?

Tags: javascript, date

For a few reasons, I have a date coming from the server as a string of "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss" format. When I create the new Date object with that string, it creates the date in local time.
To create the date correctly, I have to add the time-zone to that string: "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss PDT".

But when I get the time as a numeric value - I never add time zone when creating an object, since the numeric value is always treated as UTC.

I mean we know that [JS treats the timestamp as UTC](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp), but if a UTC value is updated with some time zone correlation, is there a way to understand it?

Maybe something like `Math.isTimePossible(ms)`.
jk ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For a few reasons, I have a date coming from the server as a string of "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss" format. When I create the new Date object with that string, it creates the date in local time.

How do you create a Date? That format isn't supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. Safari at least treats it as an invalid date.

> To create the date correctly, I have to add the time-zone to that string: "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss PDT".

That is not a good idea, see #1.

> I mean we know that JS treats the timestamp as UTC,

If by "timestamp" you mean a numeric value, then yes, they are treated as an offset in milliseconds from the ECMAScript epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). A timestamp is anything that can be interpretted as a date or time, so "2020-11-13 00:00:00", "Tuesday, 11pm" and "123456" are all timestamps.

> but if a UTC value is updated with some time zone correlation, is there a way to understand it?

It's not clear what you mean, UTC is UTC. If you want to parser strings that aren't in one of the formats supported by ECMA-262 (which are limited to the same formats as produced by *toString* and *toISOString*) then write a bespoke function or use a library. There are some that allow specifying offset information using IANA representative locations, such as [Luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon) and [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/Getting-Started).

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. 
Weirdly enough, the string was actually parsing. But what I was looking for is if you can define whether the date in numeric format is actually a UTC, or changed according to the time zone. 
I see this is not possible and your answer actually explained a few additional things. 
Thank you!